# Asking about country

Tags: prepositions, questions

I want to know country of some person.

What's right question?

**What country is he from?**
OR
**From what country is he?**

Or maybe the both options are wrong, aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What country is he from?*

This is the way I would say it. Perhaps you're worried about using that version, because you were told it was not proper to end a sentence with a prepostion. That piece of advice is widely disregarded nowadays. Simple type this into Google:

```
  Is it okay to end a sentence with a prepostion
```

and you'll find plenty of credible sources assuring you that doing so is not a problem.

Your second version is not ungrammatical, but it does sound stilted.

Comment: Thank you very much! I know that english sentence can end with a preposition. But I really wanted to know this sentence is such sentence or not.
About second option I was confused by question that is leading with word "From".

Answer (score 0):

**Where are you from?** and **What country are you from?** are polite questions. Asking something else might end up being offensive or rude.

Comment: I am asking about grammar. What question is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask like this :

```
Do you know where is he from?
```

Comment: I know that I can ask other question. for example: where does he live? But I want to know what question of above questions is right.

Comment: Ok, I don't know the rule but I would put my bet on the first one